# How to return data from AJAX into keyup event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have got created AJAX request. In this request I got two arrays and I want to have this AJAX request in keyup event and in this event i want to continue work with this two arrays.

**REQUEST:**

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState < 4) {
    return;
  }
  if (ajax.status !== 200) {
    return;
  }
  if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
    data = ajax.responseText;
    x = data.slice(0, data.indexOf("|"));
    y = x.replace(/"/g, "");
    z = y.replace(/[\[\]]+/g, "");
    let stopwords = z.split(",");
    a = data.slice(data.indexOf("|") + 1);
    let terms = JSON.parse(a);
  }
};
ajax.open("GET", search_x.ajaxurl + "?action=search_terms", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json", "charset= UTF-8");
ajax.send();
```

**EVENT**

```
searchForm.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  //work with stopwords and terms
});
```

Comment: did you try to put ajax function in keyup event?

Comment: yes, I have succes AJAX request, but I cant work with the data anymore. I can't create "callback" function.

Comment: Please add your complete code, don't see your success request?

Comment: @Asif i already deleted it. I just need help with creating the callback function.

Comment: try something like this `ajax.success = function(){ }`

Comment: @Asif Created this https://jsfiddle.net/mckvak/jtdc3z07/, but still I cant acces terms inside keyup event. Its what I need.

Comment: HTML code is missing there?

Comment: @Asif U dont need HTML dude

Comment: You have added event on searchForm? and when you are triggering this event in HTML?

Comment: Are you able to fire ajax call on click event ?

Comment: @Sudarshan yep i receive XHR. If i console log terms and stopwords in onreadyfunction I got arrays with values. But I need to trigget XHR in keyup event and work with terms and stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add keyup event listener to your search box

```
<input id="searchBox" onkeyup="return getSuccessOutput()" placeholder="Search here" />
```

[Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2qsyuex5/)

Comment: @mckvak you can modify this jsfiddle example and show me if you are still facing difficulty.